# Reordering table rows on server side

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html-table

I have a table which contains asp radiobuttonlists (see below) for a survey. Once submitted the results are written to a database.

I would like to use this same table for a similar survey, but the trouble is the question order needs to be different. The questions are the same, just in a different order.

Is there a way (server side) to change the order of the table rows?

```
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>EXCELLENT</td>
              <td>GOOD</td>
              <td>AVERAGE</td>
              <td>POOR</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>Question 1</td>
              <td colspan="4" class="radiocell"><asp:RadioButtonList ID="question1" runat="server" CssClass="radiooptions" RepeatColumns="4" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0">
                <asp:ListItem id="answer1_1" runat="server" Value="1" Text="" />                
                <asp:ListItem id="answer1_2" runat="server" Value="2" Text="" />                
                <asp:ListItem id="answer1_3" runat="server" Value="3" Text="" />                
                <asp:ListItem id="answer1_4" runat="server" Value="4" Text="" />                
              </asp:RadioButtonList></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>Question 2</td>
              <td colspan="4" class="radiocell"><asp:RadioButtonList ID="question2" runat="server" CssClass="radiooptions" RepeatColumns="4" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0">
                <asp:ListItem id="answer2_1" runat="server" Value="1" Text="" />                
                <asp:ListItem id="answer2_2" runat="server" Value="2" Text="" />                
                <asp:ListItem id="answer2_3" runat="server" Value="3" Text="" />                
                <asp:ListItem id="answer2_4" runat="server" Value="4" Text="" />                
              </asp:RadioButtonList></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>Question 3</td>
              <td colspan="4" class="radiocell"><asp:RadioButtonList ID="question3" runat="server" CssClass="radiooptions" RepeatColumns="4" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0">
                <asp:ListItem id="answer3_1" runat="server" Value="1" Text="" />                
                <asp:ListItem id="answer3_2" runat="server" Value="2" Text="" />                
                <asp:ListItem id="answer3_3" runat="server" Value="3" Text="" />                
                <asp:ListItem id="answer3_4" runat="server" Value="4" Text="" />                
              </asp:RadioButtonList></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the ASP.Net [DataList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) or [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) instead and sort the DataSource accordingly.

Comment: This probably is the best solution so I'll give you the tick. For my purposes though I have just made sure the question order can be the same in different forms. Thanks